# Scrapy Start_request parse

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writing a scrapy script to search and scrape result from a website. I need to search items from website and parse each url from the search results. I started with Scrapy's `start_requests` where i'd pass the search query and redirect to another function `parse` which will retrieve the urls from the search result. Finally i called another function **parse_item** to parse the results. I'm able to extract the all the search results url but i'm not being able to parse the results ( `parse_item` is not working). Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class xyzspider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'dspider'
    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]
    mylist = ['Search item 1','Search item 2']
    url = 'https://example.com/search?q='

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in self.mylist:
            i = i.replace(' ','+')
            starturl = self.url+ i

            yield Request(starturl,self.parse)

    def parse(self,response):
        itemurl =  response.xpath(".//section[contains(@class, 'search-results')]/a/@href").extract()
        for j in itemurl:
            print j
            yield Request(j,self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self,response):
        print "hello"

        '''rating = response.xpath(".//ul(@class = 'ratings')/li[1]/span[1]/text()").extract()
        print rating'''
```

Could anyone please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a **Filtered offsite request** error. I changed the allowed domain from `allowed_domains = www.xyz.com` to 
`xyz.com` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good. So you might need to use the Request attribute dont_filter set to True:

```
yield Request(j,self.parse_item, dont_filter=True)
```

From the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html):

> dont_filter (boolean) – indicates that this request should not be filtered by the scheduler. This is used when you want to perform an identical request multiple times, to ignore the duplicates filter. Use it with care, or you will get into crawling loops. Default to False.

Anyway I recommend you to have a look at the item Pipelines. 
Those are used to process scraped items using the command:

```
yield my_object
```

[Item pipelines](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) are used to post-process everything yielded by the spider.